# Blazor: Event sent from Service to Component is null

Tags: events, .net-core, service-worker, blazor

I have program composed of Blazor component and Worker Service. I'm using .NET CORE 3.1

I've based my code on manual to [Blazor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

At my worker service's side I have:

```
    public event Func<double, Task> Notify;
    public double Data{ get; set; }

    public async Task Update(double data)
    {
        if (Notify != null)
        {
            await Notify.Invoke(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
             await Update(Data).ConfigureAwait(false);
             ...

             await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

In my Blazor Component:

```
@using MyNamespace
@inject WorkerService MyService
@implements IDisposable

<div>@DataToDisplay</div>

@code {

    private double DataToDisplay{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MyService.Notify += OnNotify;
    }

    public async Task OnNotify(double data)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            DataToDisplay= data;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MyService.Notify -= OnNotify;
    }
}
```

After debugging I notified, that Notify event is properly wired in Blazor component, in OnInitialized() method (I've tried also the version with `OnInitializedAsync()` ) however, every time, when service calls `Update()` method, during the condition check: `if (Notify != null)`, the Notify is null.

I can't find the reason. Thank you for any suggestions !

Comment: What does your dependency injection look like out of interest? is MyService a singleton?

Comment: Indeed. Startup.cs contains i.e.: `services.AddSingleton<WorkerService>();`

Comment: Who's initiating the service ? I guess by calling ExecuteAsync, right ? Try your code without using ConfigureAwait...perhaps the issue lies here. You can never know...

Comment: It is not the ConfigureAwait. I tried the code above out in two ways. Fist I did not Implemented the service as a Hosted service. I added a button to start the ExecuteAsync method. The UI got update as expected. 
I changed the service implementation to hosted service, so I need to change the DI registration to ```AddHostedService```. This caused an error that indicated that the service is not added to the DI and the component cannot inject it. Added it a singletone as well. No errors but, UI is not updated and the Notify is null.Actually this way you have 2 independent instace of the service.

Comment: Of course the above comment assumes that this happened. I was able to make this work by creating a different none hosted service that is injected into the component it self and in the hosted service. The hosted service calls the update method of the injected service. The implementation of the event was moved from the hosted service to the injectable service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class InjectableService
    {
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public event Func<Task> Notify;
        public double Data { get; set; }

        public  async Task RefreshAsync(double value)
        {
            if (Notify is { })
            {
                Value = value;
                await Notify.Invoke();
            }
        }
```

```
public class MyService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly InjectableService _injectableService;

        public MyService(InjectableService injectableService)
        {
            _injectableService = injectableService;
        }

        public async Task Update(double value)
        {
            await _injectableService.RefreshAsync(value);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Update(_injectableService.Value + 0.1).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
@inject InjectableService MyService
@implements IDisposable

<p>@MyService.Value</p>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MyService.Notify += OnNotify;
    }

    public async Task OnNotify()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MyService.Notify -= OnNotify;
    }
}
```

In the Startup.cs:

```
services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
services.AddSingleton<InjectableService>();
```

Comment: Thank you. Your observations make sense and explains why the event is null in HostedService - there must be running two instances of the service. I'll try your solution as workaround. That's curious behavior, that the service is created twice as singleton.

Comment: I have found description here: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/553 that hosted service shouldn't be treated as API (second comment). Injecting intermediate service really helped. Still, I can't understand, why hosted service even set as Singleton doesn't behave like that. Thank you @ZsoltBendes !

Answer (score 2):

Basing on the discussion on github : https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/553
I have that HostedServices are Transient since .NET Core 2.1.

However there is possibility to use it as API, what is described at the bottom of that thread:

in Startup.cs, in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`:

```
services.AddSingleton<BackgroundWorkerService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(p => p.GetService<BackgroundWorkerService>());
```

And this apparently works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a simliar problem like yours, as I wanted to Update some Elements in the UI by using an event.

Looking at the Service Registration Methods, from the official Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-registration-methods), 
`services.AddSingleton<IMyDep, MyDep>();`
was the way to go, since it allowed multiple Implementations.

All I had to do was creating a class with an Interface:

```
public interface INotifierService
{
    // In an Interface, its all Public!


    delegate void UiChangedEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);

    event UiChangedEventHandler UiChanged; //Handler


}
```

and another class which derives from that Interface:

```
public class NotifierService:INotifierService
{

    public event INotifierService.UiChangedEventHandler UiChanged; //Event from the base Interface

    protected virtual void OnUiChanged()
    {
        UiChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

}
```

and register them in `Startup.cs:`

```
        services.AddSingleton<Services.INotifierService, Services.NotifierService>();
```

and it worked well!

Of course, don't forget to inject the Interface into your .razor file and subscribe to its event!